# How can I get the min and max date per day of employees with location?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question is similar to the question posted here: [How can I get the min and max date per date of employees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624279/how-can-i-get-the-min-and-max-date-per-date-of-employees), but with one additional requirement.  If the table has an additional location column such as:

| Employee_Number | DateTime | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00000001 | 2014/01/14 09:20 | Wendys |
| 00000001 | 2014/01/14 12:35 | McDonalds |
| 00000001 | 2014/01/14 13:35 | Walmart |
| 00000002 | 2014/01/14 09:20 | Arbys |
| 00000001 | 2014/01/14 22:49 | Burger King |
| 00000001 | 2014/01/15 09:35 | Sonic |
| 00000001 | 2014/01/15 10:35 | Dairy Queen |
| 00000001 | 2014/01/15 17:35 | Arbys |
| 00000002 | 2014/01/14 12:34 | McDonalds |
| 00000002 | 2014/01/14 17:34 | Subway |

And having a SELECT statement that outputs:

| Employee_Number | DateTime | MIN | MAX | MIN Location | MAX Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000001 | 2014/01/14 | 2014/01/14 09:20 | 2014/01/14 22:49 | Wendys | Burger King |
| 00000001 | 2014/01/15 | 2014/01/15 09:35 | 2014/01/15 17:35 | Sonic | Arbys |
| 00000002 | 2014/01/14 | 2014/01/14 09:20 | 2014/01/14 17:34 | Arbys | Subway |

Thanks for any help!

Comment: tag your database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: The duplicate shows the general technique - you need to apply the row_number logic twice to get first (ascending) and first (descending). There are, of course, other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your table:

```
create table MyTable (
    Employee_Number int,
    DateTime    datetime,
    Location    varchar(20)
)

insert into MyTable values
(00000001,  '2014/01/14 09:20:00',  'Wendys'),
(00000001,  '2014/01/14 12:35:00',  'McDonalds'),
(00000001,  '2014/01/14 13:35:00',  'Walmart'),
(00000002,  '2014/01/14 09:20:00',  'Arbys'),
(00000001,  '2014/01/14 22:49:00',  'Burger King'),
(00000001,  '2014/01/15 09:35:00',  'Sonic'),
(00000001,  '2014/01/15 10:35:00',  'Dairy Queen'),
(00000001,  '2014/01/15 17:35:00',  'Arbys'),
(00000002,  '2014/01/14 12:34:00',  'McDonalds'),
(00000002,  '2014/01/14 17:34:00',  'Subway')
```

This would be your query:

```
with MyResult (Row_num_min, Row_num_max, Employee_Number, DateTime, Location)
    as
    (
      select 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_Number, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DateTime)) order by DateTime) AS ROW_NUM_MIN,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_Number, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DateTime)) order by DateTime DESC) AS ROW_NUM_MAX,
        Employee_Number, 
        DateTime, 
        Location
      from MyTable
    )
    select
      Employee_Number,
      DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DateTime))as DateTime,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Row_num_min = 1 THEN DateTime END) AS MIN,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Row_num_max = 1 THEN DateTime END) AS MAX,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Row_num_min = 1 THEN Location END) AS MIN_Location,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Row_num_max = 1 THEN Location END) AS MAX_Location
    from MyResult
    where row_num_min = 1 or row_num_max = 1
    group by 
      Employee_Number,
      DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DateTime))
    order by 
      Employee_Number,
      DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DateTime))
```

And this is the result (the same as you expected):

```
| Employee_Number |             DateTime |                  MIN |                  MAX | MIN_Location | MAX_Location |
|-----------------|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|--------------|--------------|
|               1 | 2014-01-14T00:00:00Z | 2014-01-14T09:20:00Z | 2014-01-14T22:49:00Z |       Wendys |  Burger King |
|               1 | 2014-01-15T00:00:00Z | 2014-01-15T09:35:00Z | 2014-01-15T17:35:00Z |        Sonic |        Arbys |
|               2 | 2014-01-14T00:00:00Z | 2014-01-14T09:20:00Z | 2014-01-14T17:34:00Z |        Arbys |       Subway |
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0a4b74/26

Comment: @Jared1773 if this solved your problem, do not forget to mark it as accepted answer, please (and optionally upvote it). Thank you